# Trying to build c++ for a remote arm device on QtCreator, executable is 64bit

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, arm

I have a board with zynq chipset and Armv7 processor and Ubuntu 12.04. I want to remotely build and debug a c++ program on it with QtCreator. 
I tried to create a kit for building the program [using this link](http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Zynq+Qt+and+Qwt+Base+Libraries-Build+Instructions). added the compiler in the toolchains of board and added qt version 4.8.1 to the kit (version of qt on the board is 4.8.1).

The code builds successfully. the problem is the binary is not executable on my board because it seems it is a 64bit binary and my board is not 64bit.
Am I missing something?

how can I check if my config for compiling qt everywhere source was correct and it  resulted in the qmake I wanted?

btw my own OS is Ubuntu 16.04 64bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after hours and hours of searching and trying different things I found the reason. First of all as @michal-f said I installed 32-bit Ubuntu. making in terminal was resulting in ARM binary but QtCreator just compiled for intel proccessor.

as stupid as it seems the reason was that I did not know that Qt variables is not related to system variables and though I had added `CROSS_COMPILE` variable in terminal, I should have added it to my kit environmental variables too.

so the phrase `${CROSS_COMPILE}g++` in MakeFile was simply g++ and the output was a binary compile with system g++.

I know it was something I should have found sooner, but something this stupid should have been somewhere on internet for beginners like me. So hopefully next person encountering this same problem will find this post.

Answer (score 0):

The instruction on the Xilinx's page instruct how to build a cross compiler for ARM, however I belive they assumed you're going to follow these steps on 32-bit Linux platform. On the other hand `-xplatform qws/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++` option should produce 32bit compiler.

Are you sure your code is build with right compiler build with right option? have you trie to build any minimal example from command line and check what `file` command is telling you about the binary produced? For me it looks like, do don't really cross-compile your project.

Comment: I double checked the compiler in my kit. it is the g++ compiler provided in the board CD and running -v on it tells the target is `arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi`. and yes compiling a sample hello world with the kit results in a 64-bit binary.

Comment: So if your ARM on Zynq is 32 bit, then you have the wrong compiler - sorry. Ask Xilinx for help.